# How to find double regex substrings in string?

Tags: python, regex, string, python-3.x, substring

I want to find double substrings in a string using a regex.

Example:

```
line = "text 04/22/2014 text 04/22/2015 02/23/2014 more text 04/22/2014 more text 02/23/2014"

myregex= "\d\d/\d\d/\d\d\d\d"
```

I know how to check if the regex matches the strings:

```
mymatches = regex.findall(myregex, line)  
len(mymatches )
```

this returns the length of the list of matches.
if the list is `>1` than there are doubles in the string

But what I don't know is to find the doubles of the **same** strings, in above case `04/22/2014` and `04/22/2014` and put them in a nested list.
example output: `[['04/22/2014','04/22/2014'],['02/23/2014', '02/23/2014']]`
How can I find the doubles of the same regex strings?

Comment: Could you provide the output that would be associated with the input you've given?

Comment: @PatrickHaugh, I updated my question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, we'll find all the matches to that pattern in the line.  Then we will sort them and group the identical ones together.

```
import re
import itertools 

line = "text 04/22/2014 text 04/22/2015 02/23/2014 more text 04/22/2014 more text 02/23/2014"

pat = r'\d\d/\d\d/\d\d\d\d'
reg = re.compile(pat)
print([list(g) for k, g in itertools.groupby(sorted(reg.findall(line)))])
```

Output:

```
[['02/23/2014', '02/23/2014'], ['04/22/2014', '04/22/2014'], ['04/22/2015']]
```

EDIT: If you want only those strings that appear twice or more, you can do something more like

```
[g for g in map(lambda x: list(x[1]), itertools.groupby(sorted(reg.findall(line)))) if len(g) > 1]
```

Comment: Wow. impressive :)  Thank you

Comment: Hope you don't mind if I ask you one more question. I would like to filter the list like you do but when the dates respected the regex only (NOT the same string). Please see my first example `mymatches = regex.findall(myregex, line) ` --> `My output = ['04/22/2014', '04/22/2015', '02/23/2014', '04/22/2014', '02/23/2014']` - How can I filter the list like you do if len(list) > 1?

Comment: @Reman I'm not sure i understand.  Are you asking how to see only those dates that appear more than once?  If so, see my edit.

Comment: Please see the 1st part of my question where I write that I know how to match all strings matching the regex (strings which are not always the same but matched the regex). My output is in that case: `mymatches = regex.findall(myregex, line)` -->  `['04/22/2014', '04/22/2015', '02/23/2014', '04/22/2014', '02/23/2014']` - How can I filter the list like you do if len(list) > 1 (using list comprehension)?

Comment: @Reman I'm taking `mymatches`, passing it to `sorted`, and then passing that to `itertools.groupby`  `groupby(sorted(mymatches))`.  This will give us `k, g` pairs where `k` is some value in our list, and `g` is an iterator that yields that value the number of times it appears in our list.  We want to capture only `g`, and have that value in some container we can measure the size of, so we do `map(lambda x: list(x[1]), groupby(sorted(mymatches)))`.  Now we just want to extract the lists out of `map` and keep the ones that are greater than `1`, so we do the last line in my edit.

Comment: `[g for g in map(lambda x: list(x[1]), itertools.groupby(sorted(reg.findall(line)))) if len(g) > 1]`

Comment: I think I was not enough clear. Your answer resolved my question. My question was about to find doubles of the SAME string. If I want to capture all regex matches (Same string and not the same string) my output will be a flat list. I would like to use list comprehension and filter the list (as in your solution) > 1.

Comment: I would pass the list into a `Counter`.  `c = collections.Counter(mymatches)` then `[item for item in c if c[item] > 1]`

Comment: Yes! Thank you very much for your great answer and your support :)

Answer (score 2):

```
import re

line = "text 04/22/2014 text 04/22/2015 02/23/2014 more text 04/22/2014 more text 02/23/2014"

datefreq = {}

p = re.compile(r'(\d{2}/\d{2}/\d{4})')
for f in p.findall(line):
    datefreq[f] = datefreq.setdefault(f, 0) + 1
for key in sorted(datefreq.keys()):
    print("{0}, {1}".format(key, datefreq[key]))
```

This outputs:

```
02/23/2014, 2
04/22/2014, 2
04/22/2015, 1
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by using *referencing*, your regex will look like:

```
myregex= r"(\d\d/\d\d/\d\d\d\d).*?\1"
```

where `\1` refers to the firs group (between the brackets) [[source]](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#regular-expression-syntax).

You thus search for a pattern `\d\d/\d\d/\d\d\d\d` and then take an arbitrary number of characters followed by exactly the same pattern.

There is however one catch: the patterns in `findall` are **not supposed to overlap**. So `"04/22/2014 02/23/2014 04/22/2014 02/23/2014"`. You can solve this using `search`: you ask to search for a first element, then look at the `pos`, and look for a next pattern with `start+1`. Something like:

```
import re

myregex= re.compile(r"(\d\d/\d\d/\d\d\d\d).*?\1")
line = "04/22/2014 02/23/2014 14/5/1992 04/22/2014 02/23/2014"

pos = 0
result = []
while pos >= 0:
    srch=myregex.search(line,pos)
    if srch:
        result.append(srch.group(1))
        pos = srch.start()+1
    else:
        pos = -1
```

This gives:

```
$ python3
Python 3.5.2 (default, Nov 17 2016, 17:05:23) 
[GCC 5.4.0 20160609] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import re
>>> 
>>> myregex= re.compile(r"(\d\d/\d\d/\d\d\d\d).*?\1")
>>> line = "04/22/2014 02/23/2014 14/5/1992 04/22/2014 02/23/2014"
>>> 
>>> pos = 0
>>> result = []
>>> while pos >= 0:
...     srch=myregex.search(line,pos)
...     if srch:
...         result.append(srch.group(1))
...         pos = srch.start()+1
...     else:
...         pos = -1
... 
>>> result
['04/22/2014', '02/23/2014']
```